# HTML scraping returns template

Tags: html, screen-scraping, urllib

I've been trying to extract data from a website using different methods (urllib & lxml for example).

My problem:

The HTML-files I recieve are the templates for the website. For example, I recieve  `{{price}}` instead of `$3,543`.

Is there some general solution to this? Please ask if you need more information (not that I have a lot of it).

Thanks!

Comment: well, certainly the first information to add is the url you try to scape! Then you should add your atempts, so that we can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the page, you'll find some JavaScript is automatically submitting a form. The response will contain the price you want, so you need to find the request that's being made, and replicate it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm kind of new to the interaction between HTML and JavaScript.